# I want to display results that are within the current month

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

I want to display results that are within the current month

example

Select * FROM table_name WHERE date="THIS MONTH"...

What can I replace THIS MONTH with to get the results for the current month

Answer (score 1):

Use a date function to extract the month and compare to the number for the month you are trying to match against:-

```
Select * FROM table_name WHERE MONTH(date)= [0 - 11];
```

You may need to match against the right year too:-

```
Select * FROM table_name WHERE MONTH(date) = month(current_timestamp) and year(date) = year(current_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:-

```
Select * FROM table_name WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_field,"%m")= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%m");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 select * from tableName
 where month(dateField) = month(now())
 and year(dateField)= year(now());
```